# update a list of value in textfield in struts2

Tags: struts2, iterator

I am facing a problem in Struts2, In my sample application I have Array of objects (Say person name) , I need to display these names as a editable text fields , I am using Iterators for this , I am successful in diaplying, But When I cange the same value and submit the form. I am getting the entire array which holds null value.

Say for Exaple in my form bean I have a property
Name [] names;

In my JSP I have the iterator as

If there are 3 names then I can get these names on the UI if I can initialized them with some dummy value but when I edit and sumbit, then "names" array is not getting updated. Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Struts2, when you need to repopulate the list of bean items, you need to refer them through indices. Please refer the example below:

Bean class:

```
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Action class:

```
public class PersonAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<Person> persons;

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    //Initial Load method
    @Override
    public String execute() {
        persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

        int alpha = 65;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setId(i);
            person.setName(String.valueOf((char)alpha++));
            persons.add(person);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    //Function that handles the form submit
    public String updatePerson() {

        for(Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person.getId() + ":" + person.getName());
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<s:form action="doUpdate">
         <s:iterator value="persons" status="stat" var="person">
              <s:textfield value="%{#person.name}" name="persons[%{#stat.count}].name"/><br/>
         </s:iterator>
         <s:submit value="Submit"/>
</s:form>
```

When you submit the above form, the url would look like `doUpdate?persons[0].name=A1&persons[1].name=B1&persons[2].name=C1`. Similarly if you need to update id of the first person object, you will append `persons[0].id=3` to the url using form. In the `<s:textfield value="%{#person.name}" name="persons[%{#stat.count}].name"/>`, you tell that the predefined value is person's name, for each object. The `name` attribute is to set the rendered html input element; the name which will be referenced in the url when the form is submitted. You will get a clear idea if you look into the generated html.

Comment: thanks for your response. this one works for me. For my case, it is a little bit trickier. I just have another list in person object, it is called state. like below:

Comment: public class State {
 private int id;
 private String stateAbbr;
...  setter, getter ..

the Page below

<s:form action="doUpdate">
<s:iterator value="persons" status="stat" var="person">
 <s:textfield value="%{#person.name}"
 name="persons[%{#stat.count-1}].name" />
  <s:iterator value="%{#person.states}" status="stateStatus" var="personState">
 <s:textfield value="%{#personState.stateAbbr}"
  name="states[%{#stateStatus.count-1}].stateAbbr" label="Abbr State" />
   </s:iterator>
 </s:iterator>
 </s:submit value="Submit" />
 </s:form>

states in Person is null? something wrong with my Page?

Comment: See, when you submit the form, states[%{#stateStatus.count-1}].stateAbbr should match to some person. Otherwise, it is of no use. Hence, make this change: <s:textfield value="%{#personState.stateAbbr}" name="persons[%{#stat.count-1}].states[%{#stateStatus.count-1}].stateAbbr" label="Abbr State" />

Comment: I think the count should not be use in this place. If you want to use count, we should use like this.                                                                       <s:textfield value="%{#person.name}" name="persons[%{#stat.count} - 1].name"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use the iterator tag of struts2, if list is not empty then use :

```
<s:iterator value="names" status="namesStatus">
    <s:property/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```